# Java Servlet Filter Equivalent in Ruby [on Rails] and PHP?

Tags: java, php, python, ruby-on-rails, servlets

Not sure if the terminology is correct, but are there rough equivalents to Java Servlet Filters in Ruby and PHP ? Are they actual concrete *classes* ?

I assume there is also a number of common web app libraries/frameworks in Python. Is there an equivalent there ?

Thanks.

**=== ADDENDUM ===**

On the good advice of [Kevin Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49993/kevin-davis), I just want to quickly elaborate on what Java Servlet Filters are. It is basically an HTTP request interceptor. A chain of filters can be configured between the raw receipt of the request and the final destination of the request. The request parameters (and cookies, headers etc. etc.) are passed to the first filter in the chain and each filter does something with them (or not) and then passes them up the chain (or not. eg. a caching filter may simply return the result, bypassing the rest of the chain and the endpoint).

One of the advantages is the ability to modify or enhance the web app without touching the original endpoint code.

Cheers.

Comment: It might help to describe what they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume there is also a number of
>   common web app libraries/frameworks in
>   Python. Is there an equivalent there ?

**Django** provides a framework of middleware hooks that can be used to alter input/output in request/response processing. See the [Middleware documentation page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical **Apache/PHP** scenario, the answer is generally: No, there are no custom filters. However, there some solutions for problems solved with Java Servlet Filters:

- There are multiple collaborating [access control modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)
- Compression can be set in [the php configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression)

You can create a [`.htaccess` file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) to set those properties for a directory and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby on Rails has filters](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) that serve this purpose

A new feature is [Rack Middleware](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2009/02/its-only-rack-on-rails-but-i-like-it/), which is similar to Django middleware

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP world, [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) provides a plugin API for its front controller object that allows hooking of plugin objects between the pre-routing and post-dispatching phases. Although I didn't have a chance to work with Java servlets I assume this would match the descripton in your addendum. Anyway, this is not built into PHP, its framework dependent as with RoR or Django.